# How can I know which class is from interface

Tags: java, eclipse

I using eclipse and and when I write this code

```
for (Property property : properties)
{                                           
property.getType();
```

and use `CTRL+1` Im getting this suggestion which is valid

```
IPropertyTypeU type = property.getType();
```

but there is specific casting which I want to use like

```
SimpleType simpletype = ((SimpleTypeU) property).getSimpleType();
```

I found this option just when I used the where used option (CTRL+SHIFT+G)

1. There is more convenient way to do that ?
2. There is easy way to see who is extending from specific interface
   for example if I click on IPropertyTypeU I see all the class/interface that he extends 
   but how can I easily know that SimpleType extends IPropertyTypeU ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the characters of the Class "IPropertyTypeU" in the Editor and press F4.

You will be able to see 4 different kinds of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

While F4 gives you elaborate information about super class members of class, variables and method, ctrl+T should give you quick view about hierarchy of types. However in this hierarchy you can only see the classes (abstract and non abstract super classes), but not interfaces.